# Euler class and self-intersection number of a surface in a 4-manifold

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

In the first two paragraphs of [Circle bundles over $CP^1$ and self-intersection number of $CP^1$ embeddings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130740/circle-bundles-over-cp1-and-self-intersection-number-of-cp1-embeddings), it is claimed that

> For a compact oriented surface $X$ in a 4-dimensional oriented manifold $M$, the self-intersection number $X^2$ is given by the integral over $X$ of the Euler class of the normal bundle.

Does anybody have a reference with proof for this result? My standard reference for characteristic classes is Milnor & Stasheff (§9 is about the Euler class), but it seems the result is not there.

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_class

Comment: In the meantime I have found http://mathoverflow.net/questions/696/euler-characteristic-of-a-manifold-and-self-intersection, where the question is essentially answered. Can I close my own question as duplicate? (I'm not sure what to do with this question.)

Comment: It's too late for you to do so once it's already closed, but as a moderator, I can reopen and close for a different reason. Incidentally, I hope that's a lesson to you about googling first; you can easily find a bunch of earlier questions on this topic.

Comment: I apologize for not finding the question earlier. (I *did* search the website first, though. All I came up with was http://mathoverflow.net/questions/130740/circle-bundles-over-cp1-and-self-intersection-number-of-cp1-embeddings.)